# GridDB: gs_stopclusterでクラスタが停止できない

Tags: database

GridDB V4.0 CEを使い始めました。
起動とクラスタ構成は成功したのですが、クラスタ停止でタイムアウトになってしまいました。
no_proxyの設定をいくつか試したのですが、エラーになります。
どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか？

---

```
$ export no_proxy=127.0.0.1
$ gs_startnode
$ gs_joincluster -u admin/admin -c (clusterName)

$ gs_stopcluster -u admin/admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/gs_stopcluster", line 75, in <module>
    (res, code) = util.request_rest(method, path, data, options, log)
  File "/usr/griddb-4.0.0/bin/util.py", line 81, in request_rest
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url, data, timeout=30)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1244, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1217, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1113, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 400, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.timeout: timed out

$ unset no_proxy
$ gs_stopcluster -u admin/admin
A00110: Confirm network setting. (HTTP Error 403: Forbidden)

$ export no_proxy=10.0.2.15
$ gs_stopcluster -u admin/admin
A00110: Confirm network setting. (HTTP Error 403: Forbidden)

$ hostname
vm1
$ hostname -i
10.0.2.15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プロキシ変数が設定されている場合には、プロキシにアクセスしないように no_proxy を設定する必要があります。

運用コマンドはデフォルトで 127.0.0.1 の IPアドレスを使ってサーバにアクセスします。
しかし、gs_stopcluster コマンドはマスタノードのIPアドレス(10.0.2.15)を取得した上で、そのIPアドレスにもアクセスするため、エラーになったと思われます。

プロキシ変数が設定されている場合は、$ hostname -iで出力されるIPアドレスを用いて、以下を実行してみてください。

- no_proxyを設定する。
- 運用コマンド実行時に「-s」オプションでそのIPアドレスを指定する。

---

#### 例

```
$ export no_proxy=10.0.2.15
$ gs_startnode
$ gs_joincluster -u admin/admin -c clusterName -s 10.0.0.15
$ gs_stopcluster -u admin/admin -s 10.0.2.15
$ gs_stopnode -u admin/admin -s 10.0.2.15
```

Comment: @gahohさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。

 
いただいたアドバイスをもとに対応したら、問題なくクラスタの停止ができるようになりました。

ありがとうございます。